# opengl-es glUseProgram() arugments

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

My first time trying out openGL on iOS. I have compiled the source and now I can only run the program, but how can I pass in arguments to that program for more dynamic behavious? Or do I have to compile from source every time with the argument embedded in the source?

I am looking for something like glUseProgram(myProgram, arg1, arg2);

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use that function like that.

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/

What you are looking for, is using uniforms and attributes, each is specified differently. 
It is a very extensive subject so I suggest you try reading this:

http://db-in.com/blog/2011/01/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-13/